# SQL Server Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

The query on which I am currently working returns the desired results but the problem is that I have to create an additional join with different TaskCounters for each extra column I want to add (which is of course not a rational decision).

**The query is supposed to run on SQLServer as well as on an Access DB**, so I do not need any special functions (like Pivot, CTE etc.) which are not supported in access. I need to revise that query so that the number of joins should be reduced as much as they can.

tblConsultations is the main table in which the entry for a particular child is recorded based upon the visit type (i.e. if we have 4 visits, we have 4 entries for the Consultations). The result column should display the values for those 4 visits and display NULL if there is no value against a visit.

**I want to eliminate the need for extra join from the same table which I have to add for every additional column**

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT Cast(SUBSTRING(tc2.ChildCounter, 7, LEN(tc2.ChildCounter)) AS NUMERIC) AS pkChildID
,tc2.VisitType
,tblQuitOffered.Result AS KWA_QuitOffered
,tblQuitReferral.Result As KWA_QuitReferral
FROM tblConsultations tc2
INNER JOIN tblChild tc ON tc2.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter
LEFT  JOIN tblDelivery td ON td.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT ttr.ResultCounter
    ,ttr.ChildCounter
    ,tkt.VisitType
    ,ttr.Result
    ,ttr.TaskCounter
FROM tblTaskResults ttr
INNER JOIN tlkpKeyTasks tkt ON tkt.TaskCounter = ttr.TaskCounter
    AND tkt.TaskCounter IN (
        '001410'
        ,'001463'
        ,'001431'
        )

) AS tblQuitOffered ON tc2.VisitType = tblQuitOffered.VisitType
AND tblQuitOffered.ChildCounter = tc2.ChildCounter
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  ttr.ChildCounter
    ,tkt.VisitType
    ,ttr.Result
FROM tblTaskResults ttr
INNER JOIN tlkpKeyTasks tkt ON tkt.TaskCounter = ttr.TaskCounter
    AND tkt.TaskCounter IN (
        '001411'
        ,'001464'
        ,'001432'
        )
) AS tblQuitReferral ON tc2.VisitType = tblQuitReferral.VisitType
AND tblQuitReferral.ChildCounter = tc2.ChildCounter
WHERE tc2.VisitType in (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND tc2.ConsDate BETWEEN '20130127' and '20130228'
ORDER BY tc2.ChildCounter,tc2.VisitType
```

The result is as follows:

```
pkChildID   VisitType     KWA_QuitOffered   KWA_QuitReferral
2224        1             No                No
2224        3             NULL              NULL
2224        4             NULL              NULL
2225        1             No                Yes
2225        2             Yes               Yes
2225        3             Yes               Yes
2225        4             NULL              NULL
```

Comment: I don't think you will find a single satisfactory answer that will work with both SQL Server and MS Access.  As bluefeet mentioned, the SQL syntax itself is different.  You might need different solutions for each environment.

Comment: @BellevueBob I disagree, looks like what AMS needed is just the GROUP BY clause. But what is a mystery to me is the use of TaskCounter in determining the QuitOffered and QuitReferral.

Comment: @BellevueBob - I believe I found that answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can include all the `TaskCounter` values you want in a single derived table, then use a `CASE` statement to assign your column values:

```
SELECT Cast(SUBSTRING(tc2.ChildCounter, 7, LEN(tc2.ChildCounter)) 
            AS NUMERIC) AS pkChildID
      ,tc2.VisitType

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN tktResults.TaskCounter IN (
                '001410'
               ,'001463'
               ,'001431'
               ) THEN tktResults.Result END
          ) AS KWA_QuitOffered

      ,MAX(CASE WHEN tktResults.TaskCounter IN (
                '001411'
               ,'001464'
               ,'001432'
               ) THEN tktResults.Result END
          ) AS KWA_QuitReferral

FROM  tblConsultations tc2
INNER JOIN tblChild tc 
  ON  tc2.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter
LEFT  JOIN tblDelivery td
  ON  td.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter

LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT ttr.ResultCounter
         ,ttr.ChildCounter
         ,tkt.VisitType
         ,ttr.Result
         ,ttr.TaskCounter
   FROM tblTaskResults ttr
   INNER JOIN tlkpKeyTasks tkt 
   ON tkt.TaskCounter = ttr.TaskCounter
       AND tkt.TaskCounter IN (
            '001410'
           ,'001463'
           ,'001431'
           ,'001411'
           ,'001464'
           ,'001432'
           )
   ) AS tktResults 
ON     tktResults.VisitType    = tc2.VisitType
   AND tktResults.ChildCounter = tc2.ChildCounter

WHERE tc2.VisitType in (1, 2, 3, 4)
  AND tc2.ConsDate BETWEEN '20130127' and '20130228'
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY tc2.ChildCounter,tc2.VisitType
```

If fact, you don't really need to make that a derived table (the `LEFT JOIN (...)` part), but I'm assuming you are doing that for performance reasons.  As you add columns based on different values of `TaskCounter`, just add them to the join condition.

**EDIT:** Revised to use `GROUP BY` clause with `MAX` function to return unique rows by `pkChildID` and `VisitType`.

I'm using the "ordered list" style in the `GROUP BY` clause; if that isn't supported, you may need to specify it like this:

```
GROUP BY Cast(SUBSTRING(tc2.ChildCounter, 7, LEN(tc2.ChildCounter)) AS NUMERIC)
        ,tc2.VisitType
```

I also noticed you are sorting by a column that is not part of the SELECT clause. I'm not sure why but left it intact.

Comment: There is no `CASE` in Ms Access.

Comment: @bluefeet Apparently not; but one could use VBA I think.  I missed the part about having a portable solution that included MS Access.  Don't use Access much for "real" work myself.

Comment: The difficult thing is the portability between sql server and ms access, they unfortunately do not have the same syntax, both with functions and with JOINs. MS Access requires parentheses around multiple table joins.

Comment: Hi BellevueBob, you answer is pretty close to my requirement, except that now i am seeing 2 records against each pkChildID instead of one. To further elaborate, earlier i had 7 records in the resultset (4 visit types for child (2225) and 3 visit types for child (2224)), but now it is showing 11 records to me.

Comment: The difference is like that earlier i got the result set in the following manner:
pkChildID  VisitType    KWA_QuitOffered   KWA_QuitReferral
2224       1            No                No
but now it becomes
pkChildID  VisitType    KWA_QuitOffered   KWA_QuitReferral
2224       1            No                NULL
2224       1            NULL              No
please help

Comment: By this way, I'd be getting an extra row for each extra column i want to add.

Comment: Should only require a `GROUP BY` expression with the `MAX` function.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was posting an answer some think like what BellevueBob posted.

> I think you can use Nested iif()'s instead of 'case when'

Comment: A web search also revealed to me the `SWITCH` function, which also might work for Access but alas, I don't think either would work in SQL Server.

Comment: Depending on what version of SQL Server `IIF` might not be supported.  It became available in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: ooo I see..You want some thing that works both sql and Ms Access...Ya you are right BellevueBob...

Comment: I haven't tried sql 2012 up to now but I can tell...If you would detect what DataCenter are you using dynamically by a way...maybe you can replace your query...huh?

Answer (score 0):

Often in SQL making a new table solves a problem.  Lets call it coderesolve.

It looks like this:

```
Code    QuitOffered    QuitReferral
001410  1              Null
001462  1              Null
001431  1              Null
001411  Null           1
001464  Null           1
001432  Null           1
```

You can add more columns for each "new" join you want to do.

Then your code looks like this

```
SELECT 
  Cast(SUBSTRING(tc2.ChildCounter, 7, LEN(tc2.ChildCounter)) AS NUMERIC) 
     AS pkChildID
  ,tc2.VisitType
  ,ttr.Result AS KWA_QuitOffered
  ,ttr.Result As KWA_QuitReferral
FROM tblConsultations tc2
INNER JOIN tblChild tc ON tc2.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter
LEFT  JOIN tblDelivery td ON td.ChildCounter = tc.ChildCounter
JOIN  tblTaskResults ttr on tc2.VisitType = ttr.VisitType
JOIN  tlkpKeyTasks tkt ON tkt.TaskCounter = ttr.TaskCounter
JOIN  coderesolve cr on cr.code = tkt.TaskCounter 
   AND COALESCE(cr.QuitOffered,cr.QuitReferral,0) = 1
WHERE tc2.VisitType in (1, 2, 3, 4)
AND tc2.ConsDate BETWEEN '20130127' and '20130228'
ORDER BY tc2.ChildCounter,tc2.VisitType
```

This should work on Access.  But Access is funny so no promises.

Another note, I'm assuming your codes are mutually exclusive (which gives you only one row result on the coderesolve join), if this is not the case you might have to break it into a sub-query and do a grouping or a distinct -- depends on your model.